# Is the use of DNA SNPs vs amino acid variations in the description to detail the absence or presence of a consequent amino acid variation?

Tags: dna, terminology

Studying Schizophrenia and reading some papers discussing polymorphisms in the 5HT-2A receptor gene (HTR2A). Specifically, the authors mention A-1438G, T102C, his452tyr.

Was his452tyr not described as A-1438G and T102C, in terms of a DNA SNP, because the variations in A-1438G and T102C do not give rise to a different amino acid? Histidine is coded by CAU, CAC, and tyrosine by UAU, UAC. The first position in the mRNA sequence accounts for the variance, and hence the first position in the DNA sequence. In other words, it could have been described as G-1354A (if I did that right U->A and C->G and (452*3)-2 to give the 1 position). Or is this typically a matter of original author preference, or perhaps for amino acids that would significantly change the protein?